# Many WordPress sites migration to Azure App Service

Tags: wordpress, azure

I need to migrate 75 wordpress sites to Azure.
All are just 10 page marketing websites.
Cumulative traffic is 400K (combined) for the month of April. That's roughly 5K per site.
I want to do this at : https://portal.azure.com/#create/WordPress.WordPress but was wondering :

1. if there's some automated way to do this, say via Terraform ?
2. won't 75 sites cost 75 times the price of an app ? What if I put these on a wordpress multi-site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fill out the portal UI to deploy the first website, and before you deploy the resource click `Download a template for automation` - you'll then have an IaC template that can be the basis for your automation. Terraform providers will also exist.
2. The App Service **Plan** is the billable entity in Azure. You can assign multiple Websites to the Plan. This way you can either go for 1 large plan (choose the right SKU) and try to consolidate completely, or group the apps into multiple plans.

Comment: I am thinking of using a control panel for Azure like serverpilot.io which supports Azure now. This is safer in the long run I believe.